Not able to consume the message from Kafka topic in latest Spring batch application( Spring Batch 5.x)
We developed a spring boot application using Spring Batch 4 and Spring Cloud Stream 3 earlier. Consume the data from Kafka using @EnableBinding(Sink::class) and @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT) in the consumer.
@StreamListener(target=ITestSink.CHANNEL_NAME)
public void receiveMessage(@Payload TestObj message) {
    log.info("sydney order request received message is {}",message.getName());
}

After upgrading the application with Spring 3, Spring Batch 5, and Spring Cloud Stream 4,
@EnableBinding and @StreamListener are removed in Spring Cloud Stream 3. To subscribe the Kafka topic and consume messages from the topic, we use Spring Cloud's functional approach, e.g.:
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<TestObj>> fulfillOrder() {
    return msg -> {
        // to get header - msg.getHeaders().get(key, valueType);
        // filter out bad messages
    }
}

But it's not able to subscribe to the topic in the latest Spring Boot. I observed that other Spring Boot applications without Spring Batch 5 and using only Spring Cloud Stream 4, consuming data from Kafka, are working fine using a functional approach.
Can anyone suggest any fix for consuming the data from the Kafka topic in the latest Spring batch application using a functional approach?
